# Small question on triangulation of the torus

Tags: algebraic-topology

This is Example 7.5 in Rotman‘s „An Introduction to Algebraic Topology“; we look at $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ and call the vertices $a,b,c$ and $d$, going clockwise from the upper left corner. An insertion of the diagonal $bd$ then gives a triangulation of $[0,1]\times[0,1]$, but not of the torus after the usual identifications because then the two $2$-simplexes have the same vertex set. My question is: why is this a problem? In the definition of a simplicial complex, we only required two things, namely, that faces of simplexes belong also to the complex and that intersections of two simplexes are either empty or common faces; I can‘t see why this isn't satisfied.

Thanks for any sort of clarification!

Comment: The intersection of the two 2-simplices isn't a face of either, and the 2-simplices are also glued to themselves nontrivially.  [This isn't such a big deal per se, e.g. see the "$\Delta$-complexes" in Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology."]

Comment: @yoyo Thanks, but what exactly is the intersection? Is it the the „old“ diagonal now as a closed path at the identified vertex?

Comment: The intersection of the 2-simplices is a three loops meeting at a single vertex; they share their entire boundary.

Comment: Thanks, now I see it.